# Why put a random number on the first line in header file?

Tags: c++, c

I have seen this countless of times. Instead of

```
#ifndef _common_h_
#define _common_h_

#endif /* _common_h_ */
```

people sometimes define their header files in following format:

```
#ifndef _common_h__479124197491641974591
#define _common_h__479124197491641974591

#endif /* _common_h__479124197491641974591 */
```

What is that random number good for? I just couldn't successfully google any answer to this.

Comment: in order not to collision with other common.h you might eventually include... Depending how large is your code base, it might be more or less probable. This is also very typical when you do code generation from a modeling tool.

Comment: @jsantander That means completely different common.h from different location in filesystem?

Comment: Yep... the preprocessor does not use path information when enforcing the include guards... so you including `foo/common.h` and `bar/common.h` both with the same include guard will cause the second to be skipped.

Comment: @jsantander That completely covers my question. Thank you.

Comment: This is also a problem if you are generating a library that is going to be used by a different company and you have no idea what they are going to name their headers. Adding a GUID to the header name pretty much guarantees that you will never have a name clash with another library.

Comment: The thing is `_common_h_` is a C reserved identifier for macro as is `_common_h__479124197491641974591` because of the leading `_`.

Comment: Please, when `#pragma once` will be standard? Include guards are just painful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea is to make it harder to trip your [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) unintentionally, and/or to avoid triggering someone elses' include guards.

For example, if you are writing a library, and you have a `Common.h` header, then using `_common_h_` for the guard could prevent users of your library from having `_common_h_` guards in their own libraries, which is not ideal. Adding a random number makes such collisions nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

Include guards are often declared in the form:

```
#ifndef X
#define X
    ...
#endif
```

The programmer is free to choose, what we will call here as, a "name". This name is often unique within a single library, but it can happen (even if rare) that two libraries define the same name. This can potentially lead to terrible headaches.

### The random numbers

Since the name is often not important outside of the specific file, we can choose (or other tools can do it for us) to include a random number within the name, which will make it much harder to cause name clashes.

### `#pragma once`

You can avoid the problem in another way, by using:

```
#pragma once
```

This is a well supported extension, which is compatible with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Pragma_8cpp-source.html#l00184), [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/cpp/Alternatives-to-Wrapper-_0023ifndef.html#Alternatives-to-Wrapper-_0023ifndef) and [mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), as well as many other compilers.